# Merging / Appending data frames with unequal columns ,

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

DataFrame 1   (Index is a **date**)

```
    date        Apple    Oranges ... Col100
    2020-01-01   9        10
    2002-01-02   5        12 
    ...
    2002-12-10   14       10
```

Dataframe 2

```
   date        Apple    Banana   Kiwi     Oranges... Col100
   2002-12-12   16       20       10        15
```

I want DataFrame 3 as

```
    date        Apple    Oranges   Kiwi     Banana ..... Col100 
    2020-01-01   9        10         0         0
    2002-01-02   5        12         0         0
    ...
    2002-12-10   14       10         0         0
    2002-12-12   16       15        10        20
```

I have tried

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer')
```

it just removed my index which I need absolutely.

Then I tried

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer',right_index=True, left_index=True)
```

but this is creating Apple_x, Oranges_y column and not actually appending to existing Apple oranges.
I can not pass column names while merging since I have 100s of columns in both DFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pandas `concat`:

```
res = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

which will give you `NaN` for columns without date. You can replace it with 0 as your expected output, and convert the columns back to `int` with:

```
res.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: I doubt that `res.fillna(0).astype(int)` would work. You are trying to convert complete `df` to `int`. There's a `date` column which this might fail for.

Comment: @MayankPorwal, `date` is the index. It'll not be converted at all.

Comment: My bad. I missed the part `(Index is a date)`.

Comment: Not a problem! It should fail if there's other column than numeric, though. So OP would need to update only the numeric columns.

Comment: Yes exactly my point. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It worked @CainãMaxCouto-Silva thank you.

Comment: @TarunArora, glad to help!